# Validating that all open/close parentheses are correctly matched

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, validation

It returns `true` for:

> ```
> a*(b+c)
> ()()
> (())
> ((!!(123(x))))
> ```

and returns `false` for:

> ```
> (a((b+c)) 
> )()(
> ))(( 
> (rsd+3)*(-3-a))
> ```

As you can see, the logic is simple. Can you confirm for me that it works for all-cases? I mean the logic isn't flawed.

It must be efficient and by that I mean not go over the linked list more than once.

```
public boolean parentheses()
{
    return parentheses(0,_head);
}

public boolean parentheses(int p, CharNode current)
{
    if (current == null)
    {
        if (p == 0)
         return true;
        else 
         return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if(current.getData() == ')' && p == 0)
         return false;
        else if (current.getData() == '(')
         return parentheses(p+1,current.getNext());
        else if (current.getData() == ')')
         return parentheses(p-1,current.getNext());
        else
         return parentheses(p,current.getNext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short Answer

Yes, I believe it will be functional....

### Dubious Recursion

Calling this method *recursive* is a problem. It is not a recursive method. Just because it is calling itself does not mean it is a recursive function. What you have is a bad loop. [From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29):

> A recursive function definition has one or more base cases, meaning input(s) for which the function produces a result trivially (without recurring), and one or more recursive cases, meaning input(s) for which the program recurs (calls itself).

Your code does not have a base case and a recursive case..... unless you consider `current==null` to be the base case... but that is just the recursion-terminating statement.

What I mean, is that, consider this loop:

```
boolean checkParenthesis(CharNode current) {
    int p = 0;
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.getData() == '(') {
             p++;
        } else if (current.getData() == ')') {
             p--;
        }
        if (p < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    return p == 0;
}
```

That is how you can write the code iteratively.

Now, if I change it just like this:

```
boolean checkParenthesis(CharNode current, int p) {
    if (current == null) {
        return p == 0;
    } else {
        if (current.getData() == '(') {
             p++;
        } else if (current.getData() == ')') {
             p--;
        }
        if (p < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return checkParenthesis(current.getNext(), p);
    }
}
```

What I am trying to show here is that you essentially have a while-loop that uses the stack to check the end condition.

For a long input, your code will fail with a stack-overflow exception.

### Iteration

When you have linked data like you do, the natural solution is to use iteration.

The example I have above shows how it can be done.

I am not sure why you are using recursion at all.

### Actual Recursion

If you really want to use recursion, the right way to do it would be to recurse down when you encounter a `(` value, and recurse up when you encounter a `)`

Each recursive level will make sure it has a matching parenthesis.... it will look something like:

```
// used if there is an error.
private static final CharNode ERRORNODE = new CharNode(....);
private static final CharNode ENDOFDATA = new CharNode(....);

boolean checkParenthesis(CharNode current) {
    current = matchParenthesis(current, true);
    if (current == ERRORNODE) {
        return false;
    }
    // current could be null if there was an unexpected ')' as the very last character.
    return current == ENDOFDATA;
}        

CharNode matchParenthesis(CharNode current, boolean toplevel) {
    while (current != null && current != ENDOFDATA && current != ERRORNODE) {
        if (current.getData() == ')') {
            // found our matching brace
            return current.getNext();
        }
        if (current.getData() == '(') {
            // need to start a sub-level check for a matching brace.
            current = matchParenthesis(current.getNext(), false);
        } else {
            current = current.nextData();
        }
    }
    if (current == null) {
        return toplevel ? ENDOFDATA : ERRORNODE;
    }
    return current;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention my method was a question, and it had to be recurssive, but I like your recurrsion much better ;p it does look more recurssive to me...

Answer (score 2):

You need to maintain open and closed braces count in your method, to check the validity of the closed braces.

```
boolean isValid(String s, int i, int open, int closed){
    if(i == s.length()){
        if(open != closed) return false;
        return true;
    }   

    if(s.getChar(i) == '(') open = open+1;

    if(s.getChar(i) == ')'){
        if(open > closed) closed = closed+1;
        else return false;
    } 

    return isValid(s, i+1, open, closed);
}
```

> ```
> isValid("a*(b+c)") => true
> isValid("((!!(123(x))))") => true
> isValid(" (rsd+3)*(-3-a))") => false
> isValid("(a((b+c)) ") => false
> ```

Comment: can you show me a case where my method doesn't work?

Comment: your program looks good to me and should work with all the test cases as far as I can see. Sorry didn't read your question properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive solution works, as long as the input isn't too long.  I don't recommend using recursion for this problem, since a long input could easily cause a crash from stack overflow.  An iterative solution would be more appropriate for Java.

The method name isn't descriptive enough.  Typically, a function that returns a boolean should be named `isSomething()` or `hasSomething()`.  The parameter `p` could also be named better.

The helper function should be made private.  It can also be static, since is a pure function that does not rely on any object state.

The code could be written more succinctly.

```
public boolean hasMatchingParentheses()
{
    return hasMatchingParentheses(head, 0);
}

private static boolean hasMatchingParentheses(CharNode current, int level)
{
    if (current == null)
    {
        return (level == 0);
    }

    switch (current.getData())
    {
      case ')':
        if (level == 0) return false;
        return hasMatchingParentheses(current.getNext(), level - 1);
      case '(':
        return hasMatchingParentheses(current.getNext(), level + 1);
      default:
        return hasMatchingParentheses(current.getNext(), level);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a more general case, I would implement a [Push Down Automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) using a Stack and `pushing` open parentheses on the stack and performing a `pop` for closing ones - Assuring, that the stack isn't empty. 
So every occuring closing parentheses has to match the last pushed open one.

For simple cases, a counter is sufficient enough.

Answer (score 0):

Using stack is optimal solution on this question. I would implement as below-

```
import java.util.Stack;


public class Parenthesis {

    public static boolean parenthesisCount(String s){
        if (s== null)
            return false;
        int len=s.length();
        int count=0;
        Stack<Character> pStack=new Stack<Character>();
        char ch;
        for (int i=0;i<len;i++){
            ch=s.charAt(i);

            if (ch=='(') {
                pStack.push(ch);
                count=count+1;
            }
            else{
                if ((!pStack.isEmpty()) && ch==')') {
                pStack.pop();
                count=count-1;}


            }
        }
        if (pStack.isEmpty() && count==0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(parenthesisCount("(add((sdsds)(sdsds))"));

    }

}
```

Comment: Why you have used count?